# ionic video play can't find video file

Tags: video, ionic3

```
<video width="400" controls>
  <source src="./exer.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
</video>
```

I did like above, and don't know whay browser can't find file, 
it's login.html file and in the same folder same level, I put exer.mp4 file.

[image]

should I put file in another directory???

Answer (score 0):

Use full relative path of video file.

```
<video width="400" controls>
  <source src="login/exer.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
</video>
```